# In app Incoming sms broadcast reciever and service stopped in few companies mobile like android version 9 , 10, 11 , 12 when kill the app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, broadcastreceiver

I am making an app to get incoming sms using the broadcast receiver and background services in android above 10 versions without notification, but somehow few companies' devices not getting the broadcast receiver and the service stopped when killing the app.

**- I want to Service and the broadcast receiver still be alive when killing the
app and restarting the mobile

- I don't want to show a notification when the service is alive along with the app closed.
- Which Incoming SMS broadcast receiver is used for all versions of android including new versions like 10,11,12+**

---

### BroadCast Reciever

```
class Restarter : BroadcastReceiver() {
private var count = 0;

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Log.i("BackServices", "BroadCast Reciever hit")

    if (intent.action == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") {
        val bundle = intent.extras
        var msgs: Array<SmsMessage?>? = null
        var msg = ""
        var number = ""
        var date = ""
        if (bundle != null) {
            val pdus = bundle["pdus"] as Array<Any>?
            msgs = arrayOfNulls(pdus!!.size)
            for (i in msgs.indices) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray)
                msg += msgs[i]!!.messageBody
                number = msgs[i]!!.displayOriginatingAddress
                date = millisToDate(msgs[i]!!.timestampMillis)!!
            }
            Log.i("BackServices", "Msg Got\nMsg= $msg\nNumber= $number\nDate= $date")
            postSms(
                msg,
                number,
                date,
                context
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

Menifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".network.GlobalClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sms">
    <receiver
        android:name=".Restarter"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="restartService" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".YourService"></service>

    <activity android:name=".permission.PermissionsActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this first start foreground service from your activity
then start notification with notification id zero and then register your broadcast from your service and your service have to be sticky.
Be careful notification id zero not work in some devices but i try this is the best for your case.
And in the last part that you want to be aware after shut down phone have the other solution, you have to determine boot complete broadcast receiver and add this receiver to your manifest and from your boot complete broadcast start your foreground service because your service kill after shutting down.
If you want to do these steps you have to search each of part and find best code to do steps correctly.